# Problems with Eclipse C++ and Boost BGL

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I'm having some problems to configure eclipse with the boost library. Actually my code compile without problems, but eclipse marks me some errors that the compiler does not.

I've added the path of the boost library in the includes of "paths and symbols" settings, and in fact eclipse recognizes the boost namespace, but I got several errors: for example

vector spanning_tree;

it reports as an invalid template arguments. Does anyone had my same problem?

I'm using the last version of eclipse and OS X as operating system.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't seen this particular problem, I know that in general, Eclipse CDT isn't quite as good as a full-fledged C++ compiler, and so it's not guaranteed to get every aspect of C++ correct.

Making sure that you're running the [latest version of the Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) is a good idea.

If you are running the latest version, then the Eclipse CDT developers would probably appreciate if it you [report this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/?product=CDT) as a bug.

As a last resort, you can disable the incorrect warnings (under Window, Preferences, C/C++, Code Analysis).

Comment: I've seen that on linux it works well, but unfortunately the retina display is not supported yet... so I'm forced to work with osx and I need to work with eclipse.

The problem is that even when I create a new hello world I have to include "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1" in Paths and Symbols otherwise I get errors even for std. I think that my problem is somehow related to the inclusion of the basic c++ libraries.

How could I set up eclipse so that it works even with the basic std libraries without adding the path in Path and Symbols?

Comment: @user1008538 - From what I understand, Paths and Symbols are handled by Discovery Options (under Project, Properties, C/C++ Build).  However, this is not an area of Eclipse that I understand very well.  If Eclipse is recognizing the Boost namespace after you've manually edited Paths and Symbols, then your BGL problem is unrelated, and if you have a question about discovery so that you don't have to manually edit Paths and Symbols, it's probably better posted as a separate question.